# spring security with gateway Zull Service and Eureka Server

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a Java app with Spring that has a People microservice, CRUD ok .

When I insert the security dependency in the POM of this microservice, when I make the request using the gateway URL, I always get blocked (401 forbiden) even with the correct USER and PASSWORD of the spring security, but when I put the microservice URL only, it works correctly .

For example.

GATEWAY URL- 401 forbiden, ALWAYS

http://localhost:8082/people-ms/api/people

MICROSERVICE URL - IT WORKS

http://localhost:55053/api/people

I'm lost, help me please

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then edit your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://github.com/georgefelipee/Microservice_PetHouse